# Comparing 2 Arrays to work out URL structure

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am working through a list of URL's that I am trying to work out how they are related to each other to give them a parent ID the code I have is;

```html
<?php 
$stmt = $db->query(" SELECT cd.id, cd.url FROM crawl_data cd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM site WHERE crawl_stage = 2 LIMIT 1) s ON s.id = cd.`site_id` 
ORDER BY cd.url DESC ");
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 $url = parse_url($row['url']);
 $url = (isset($url['query'])) ? $url['path'].$url['query'] : $url['path'];
 $url_parts = explode("/", $url);
 $page_depth = count($url_parts);
 if(isset($prev_url)){
  $i = 0;
  while($i < count($url_parts)){
   if($prev_url[$i] == $url_parts[$i]){
    echo "Same - ".$prev_url[$i]." - ".$url_parts[$i]."<br>";
    $i++;
   }else{
    echo "Different - ".$prev_url[$i]." - ".$url_parts[$i]."<br>";
    $prev_url = $url_parts;
    $i++;
    break;
   }
  }
 }else{
  $prev_url = $url_parts;
 }
}
?>
```

Essentially what I want it to show me is the URL's as below;

1. / (No parent ID)
2. /article (Parent ID 1)
3. /article/123 (Parent ID 2)
4. /article/1234 (Parent ID 2)
5. /article/1234/123 (Parent ID 4)
6. /about-us (Parent ID 1)

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So `explode($url)` and then build/populate a tree based on this? Should be a fun algorithm to write.

Comment: Thats exactly it, I can get it to work for a single level however having it go further than a single level deep is where I am getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
<?php
$urls = array(
  array('url' => '/', 'id' => 1),
  array('url' => '/article', 'id' => 2),
  array('url' => '/article/123', 'id' => 3),
  array('url' => '/article/1234', 'id' => 4),
  array('url' => '/article/1234/123', 'id' => 5),
  array('url' => '/about-us', 'id' => 6)
);

$tree = array(
);

function removeEmpty($segments) {
  $clean = array();
  foreach($segments as $segment) {
    if($segment !== '') {
      $clean[] = $segment;
    }
  }

  return $clean;
}

function addSegments(&$tree, $segments, &$url) {
  if(count($segments) === 0) {
    $tree['id'] = $url['id'];
    $url['leaf'] = $tree;
    return;
  }

  $segment = array_shift($segments);
  if(!array_key_exists($segment, $tree)) {
    $tree[$segment] = array(
      'parent' => $tree
    );
  }

  addSegments($tree[$segment], $segments, $url);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++) {
  addSegments($tree, removeEmpty(explode('/', 'root' . $urls[$i]['url'])), $urls[$i]);
}

foreach($urls as $url) {
  $parent = '';
  if(array_key_exists('id', $url['leaf']['parent'])) {  
    $parent = $url['leaf']['parent']['id'];
  }
  echo $url['id'] . '. ' . $url['url'] . ' (' . $parent . ')' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Producing the following output:

```
1. / ()
2. /article (1)
3. /article/123 (2)
4. /article/1234 (2)
5. /article/1234/123 (4)
6. /about-us (1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, It ran and outputted all of the urls with their ID's to the left however there was nothing within the brackets. Not sure what the errors were caused by but got alot of the following errors;

Notice: Undefined index: article_prn.aspID=801766819 in /Users/kheadley/Sites/DevArea/spider/structure.php on line 39
Notice: Undefined index: article_email.aspID=801770225 in /Users/kheadley/Sites/DevArea/spider/structure.php on line 39

Comment: Well, you fed it URLs containing query parameters, right? For that to work you need to `explode` on '?' and '&' too probably.

Comment: I did have query strings in the URL's but I have since removed them and there is still no parent url association. I am getting the following errors

Notice: Undefined index: aboutus.html in /Users/kheadley/Sites/DevArea/spider/structure.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: id in /Users/kheadley/Sites/DevArea/spider/structure.php on line 53
25. /zscaler.html ()

Comment: Please post your input dataset, it's probably some case that's not covered in my code.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => /zscaler.html
            [id] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => /virtual_disaster_recovery.html
            [id] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => /theURL,winName,features
            [id] => 45
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => /testimonials.asp
            [id] => 31
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [url] => /software-development.html
            [id] => 27
        )
)

Comment: Updated to get rid of the notices. I also ran it with your data and got `'()'`. That's to be expected, no? Because none of those have parents. If for example you added `array('url' => '/', 'id' => 1)` to the input list then all the other URLs would have `'(1)'` as parent.

Comment: Got rid of another notice from `if(!$tree[$segment]) {`. Make sure you use the updated code.